# Can't run logstash. pathname contains null byte

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to run logstash for elasticsearch but getting this error. I don't know what is the reason. Please help me.

```
[ERROR] 2020-06-14 01:17:31.633 [[main]-pipeline-manager] javapipeline - Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<ArgumentError: pathname contains null byte>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/ext/pathname/RubyPathname.java:197:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.16/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:274:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1809:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.16/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:273:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:216:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1809:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:215:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:327:in `start_inputs'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:287:in `start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:170:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:125:in `block in start'"], "pipeline.sources"=>["/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x79aee194 run>"}
[ERROR] 2020-06-14 01:17:31.667 [Converge PipelineAction::Create<main>] agent - Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
```

here is my configuration file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/rsa-key-20200528/aslogger.log"
        type => "apache"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["exaple_host:9200"]
        index => "aslogger"
    }
}
```

here is sample of my log:

```
109.169.248.247 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:25:11 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "http://almhuette-raith.at/administrator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
46.72.177.4 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
46.72.177.4 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:31:08 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "http://almhuette-raith.at/administrator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
83.167.113.100 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:31:25 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
83.167.113.100 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:31:25 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "http://almhuette-raith.at/administrator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
95.29.198.15 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:32:10 +0100] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4263 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" "-"
```

Comment: you should share pipeline.yml  and logstash.yml. and where do you written this config?

Comment: @hamidbayat you can see this in my run command:  sudo ./logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you have non-printing character in your config file. 
check with `cat -vET /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash.conf`

Comment: I don't know how to say t-h-a-n-k-s. You just save my life. The main problem was my motherfu***r FTP clients software. Everytime this software change my path location with some unwanted "@". Then I check the file according to your answer and edit this line with nano. Now everything is fine.